# Error running cron sh

Tags: linux, cron, sh

I have this file backup_mysql.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
for I in $(mysql --database=db1 -e 'show tables' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump db1 $I | gzip > "/home/user/backup/mysql/db1/$I.sql.gz";
for I in $(mysql --database=db2 -e 'show tables' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump db1 $I | gzip > "/home/user/backup/mysql/db2/$I.sql.gz";
```

and produces this error:

```
line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

when I run it in the console does not fail

Comment: Please post your cronjob line. Have you checked if you are using full paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `done` at the end of the `for` loops.  Say:

```
for I in $(mysql --database=db1 -e 'show tables' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump db1 $I | gzip > "/home/user/backup/mysql/db1/$I.sql.gz"; done
for I in $(mysql --database=db2 -e 'show tables' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump db1 $I | gzip > "/home/user/backup/mysql/db2/$I.sql.gz"; done
```

EDIT: Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983131/error-running-cron-sh/18983391?noredirect=1#comment28040769_18983391) indicates that you're still getting the error.  It seems that your file has `CR+LF` [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).  Use `dos2unix` to convert the line endings to `LF` and the problem would be gone!